# PHP long poll bug

Tags: php, long-polling

I'm trying to learn long poll and I'm using following PHP script:

```
<?php
$lastMod = filemtime('test.txt');

$counter = 10;
while ($counter > 0) {
    if (filemtime('test.txt') !== $lastMod) {
        echo file_get_contents('./test.txt');
        exit;
    }
    $counter--;
    sleep(1);
}

echo $lastMod;
```

But no matter what I do or try, it doesn't do anything when I change test.txt content during script execution.

I would be really happy if somebody told me where is the mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `filemtime` result is cached during runtime, so you need to reset it explicitly using [clearstatcache()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php).

Run it right before your `if`.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://php.net/filemtime):

> Note: The results of this function are cached. See [clearstatcache()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php)
>   for more details.